# Is this the correct way to say an integral?

Tags: integration

For this structure:

[image]

Is the correct way to verbally say this (such that a screen reader would read it aloud correctly), "The integral over the interval from negative infinity to positive infinity of f of x with respect to x"?

Comment: You can also say "The Lebesgue integral of $f$ on the reals" if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems easier to understand if you say what is being integrated first, then state the bounds of integration, so in the order:

"The integral of the function f of x with respect to x, from negative infinity to positive infinity."

Answer (score 0):

I would read it as the integral of f(x) with respect to x from negative infinity to positive infinity

or maybe the integral from negative infinity to positive infinity of f(x) with respect to x